# find entry in SQLite database on ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I followed a tutorial about creating a SQLite database, storing stuff and finding it.
What i didn't do was creating the interface since console logging can be a lot faster.
(which also doesn't require for other people to build the interace, but don't forget to import the library! :) )

This is the tutorial for incase it matters:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_6_iPhone_Application

I have a problem finding the data, does someone know what it can be?

```
- (void) findContact {
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"SELECT adress, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"", @"DoekeW"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *adressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                        (const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSLog(@"adressField: %@ phoneField: %@", adressField, phoneField);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"no match");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else {
            // 1, whatever that is
            NSLog(@"hmm %d", sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}
```

here is the complete code:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface IGViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *contactDB;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "IGViewController.h"

@interface IGViewController ()

@end

@implementation IGViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

    NSLog(@"%@", _databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath] == NO) {

        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //_status.text = @"Failed to create table";
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");

            }
            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        } else {
           // _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"database allready existed");
    }

    [self saveData];

    [self findContact];
}


- (void) saveData {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                               @"DoekeW", @"Molenstraat", @"483577"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"saved data!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"something wrong, no data saved");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}

- (void) findContact {
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"SELECT adress, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"", @"DoekeW"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *adressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                        (const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSLog(@"adressField: %@ phoneField: %@", adressField, phoneField);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"no match");
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else {
            // 1, whatever that is
            NSLog(@"hmm %d", sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I would recommend you to try out FMDB, it's much easier to work with sqlite and they have podspec for cocoapods, so setup would be breeze. An excellent [tutorial for using FMDB](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NSLog` statement in `findContact` that says:

```
NSLog(@"hmm %d", sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
```

You definitely don't want to prepare again on failure. You just want to retrieve the error message. Thus it should be:

```
NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));
```

If you did that, you would have received an error message that pointed out the misspelling of `address` in your SQL statement.

Frankly, practically every SQLite call should check its result and if not `SQLITE_OK` (or `SQLITE_ROW` or `SQLITE_DONE` for `sqlite3_step`) should, report [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

You'll find your errors far more quickly when you adopt `sqlite3_errmsg`. Let SQLite tell you precisely what the problem is!

---

As an aside, I'd also suggest:

1. I'd also advise you against ever building SQL statement with `stringWithFormat`. You'd have a problem if the name of the individual was, for example, `Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson`. Rather, you should use `?` placeholders. (You'd also be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.) Bottom line, rather than:

   ```
   NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                          @"DoekeW", @"Molenstraat", @"483577"];

   const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
       NSLog(@"saved data!");
   }
   else {
       NSLog(@"something wrong, no data saved");
   }
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   ```

   you should use:

   ```
   const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s: prepare error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [@"DoekeW" UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s: bind 1 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [@"Molenstraat" UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s: bind 2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [@"483577" UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s: bind 3 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));

   if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
       NSLog(@"saved data!");
   }
   else {
       NSLog(@"%s: step error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));
   }

   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   ```

   Basically, use [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to bind values to those `?` placeholders and eliminate the `stringWithFormat` altogether. The same is true with the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement.
2. I second Anupdas's suggestion of using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). It makes SQLite coding much easier.